# Setting List Item Level Permission for SP 2016 using CSOM

Tags: development, permissions, csom, 2016, item-level-permissions

I've been facing a very strange problem lately while working with Sharepoint Permissions using C#.

**The Scenario:**

What I want to achieve is to add a Read permission to an item (pdf document) in a sharepoint list only for a specific user. And this user is not supposed to have access to the site or the list, he should only be able to access the specified item.

Now, when I run my code, the user gets added successfully to that item and shows it in the item's permissions list inside Sharepoint.

However, when I try to open the document by logging in with that user, it shows the error, "Sorry, you do not have access to this page", which is not supposed to show, because I'm trying to open the document.

The strange part happens now. When I remove and re-add this same user in the permissions from within Sharepoint itself (not via code), the user is able to access the item correctly, as intended.

**To Summarize:**

So what's happening here is that when the permission is created via code, it does not work. And when it's added manually from Sharepoint, it works. And so far my code seems to be correct as well. It's written below:

```
private void Addpermissions(SPWeb _spWeb, int id, SPUser _user)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
            using (var spSite = new SPSite(_spWeb.Url))
            {
                spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                using (var currentWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition;
                    var spList = currentWeb.Lists["PDF(s)"];
                    var item = spList.GetItemById(id);
                    if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                    {
                        item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                        item.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    }
                    spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    roleDefinition = currentWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                    var roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(_user.LoginName, _user.Email, _user.Name,
                                                                _user.Notes);

                    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
                    item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
                    item.Update();

                    currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                    currentWeb.Dispose();
                    spSite.Dispose();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated! As I've been stuck on this issue since the past whole week.

Thanks in advnace!

Answer (score 0):

If you set permissions on item with unique permissions in SharePoint UI, it set "Limited Access" to the parents, for accesing main page, layout and etc.

If you doing this with code, it probably didn't create this limited access permissions on parents (folder/library/web/...).

Look at this feature: [Limited Access Permissions Lock](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/confusion-with-enabledisable-limited-access-user/af0e43f7-228a-4032-9029-96945fc89c1a) and try to disable/enable it.

**Try this:** **(You havent Web.EnsureUser for getting the proper user)** ***[haven't tested yet]:***

```
private void Addpermissions(SPWeb _spWeb, int id, SPUser _user)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
    {
        using (var spSite = new SPSite(_spWeb.Url))
        {
            spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            using (var currentWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
            {
                currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition;
                var spList = currentWeb.Lists["PDF(s)"];
                var item = spList.GetItemById(id);
                if (!item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                {
                    item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                    item.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                }
                spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                roleDefinition = currentWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
                //var roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(_user.LoginName, _user.Email, _user.Name, _user.Notes);

                User user = _spWeb.EnsureUser("domain\\login");

                var roleAssignment = RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
                item.RoleAssignments.Add(user, roleAssignment);
                item.Update();

                currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                spSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                currentWeb.Dispose();
                spSite.Dispose();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried what you suggested, but unfortunately it did not work.
However there's one more thing I found out, related to what you said. When I create a permission from code, a "Limited Access" permission is added to the document, along with Read. But when I create a permission from Sharepoint, "Limited Access" is not added. So is there a way to remove this "Limited Access" permission from code?

Comment: But the limit acces should be on Library and Site too, this is the cause why it is not working, try check this.

Comment: The user should not have access to the site or the library. But only to this specific document inside the library. If I provide the user permission to the site, it will work, but then the scenario will be wrong.

Comment: but user needs to have Limited Acces on Site and Library, because he needs some system resources for successfully accesing the Document in library, you dont understand this

Comment: Okay, so I checked it again, and I was wrong. The user already has limited access on the site and library. However, I'm still facing the issue. When permission created from code, it doesn't work, but when created from Sharepoint it works :(

Comment: Edited answer, try it I edited your code I hope correctly, you must ensureUser from the Web for getting correct values, example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754692/how-to-grant-user-permission-to-certain-folders-using-client-object-model